# Not getting resulted movie in PhotoLibrary iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avassetwriter, avmutablecomposition

i am creating a movie with an array of images and a audio file and saving that created movie to photo library, in simulator i am getting correct movie with my array of image and audio file but while running in device i am not getting my resulted movie instead i am getting the video what i added(OutPut.mov i used in my code) to write my output file (mixed audio and array of images file).

here is my code to save my mixed audio and array of images file to photo lib:

```
AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
NSString* audio_inputFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Ruler" ofType:@"caf"];
NSURL*    audio_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audio_inputFilePath];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;


NSString *video_inputFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"videoOutput1234videoOutput1234.mp4"];
NSLog(@"output url %@",video_inputFilePath);


NSURL*    video_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:video_inputFilePath];


NSString* outputFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"OutPut" ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL*    outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath]) 
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];


if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath]) 
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];

CMTime nextClipStartTime = kCMTimeZero;

AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_inputFileUrl options:nil];
CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);
AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

[a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];



AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];
CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);
AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];


AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];   
_assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
_assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

[_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void ) {[self saveVideoToAlbum:outputFilePath]; }       ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the video file into the photolibrary path like..

```
- (void)writeVideoToPhotoLibrary:(NSURL *)url
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    
    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Video could not be saved");
        }
    }];
    [library release];
}

- (void)video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {
    // Let's see what happened
    NSLog(@"finished");
    NSLog(@":error : %@", error);
}
```